# Geofencing Xamarin Android not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, geofencing

We have a problem in implementing Geo-fencing in Xamarin Android. There is no documentation found for Geo-fencing for monodroid. So we have tried it by simply porting the Android code to Xamarin with the new Geo-fencing API that uses 'LocationServices' from the below link.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing

But this is not working in xamarin. The same native Android code is returning the Geo-fence transition events.

We are using GooglePlayServices version 22.0.0.0 library.

We have also attempted the example given in below link, which is actually a monodroid sample. This implementation is based on the deprecated class 'LocationClient'. For this we have downgraded the 'GooglePlayServices' to version 21.0.0.

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/wear/Geofencing

But this is also not working. In both implementations the connection callbacks are fired. That is we will get Geo-fence added messages. And the Service is also started. But the transition events such as 'Initial Trigger', 'Transition Enter', 'Transition Exit' not firing. Please advice on this.